# Caja not connecting anymore to sftp://

Tags: sftp, caja

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 22.04.4 LTS (jammy) with the Caja file manager version 1.26.0 and I want to have a connection with a file server over SSH using SFTP.

But when I type `sftp://user@192.168.0.1` in the address bar, I get this error:

[image]

In the previous LTS version of Ubuntu, this always used to work fine. But now, it gives this "could not display/error connection failed" error message:

[image]

I do have SSH access to this server. I thought it might be a missing SSH/SFTP package for Caja, but I cannot find anything related in Synaptic.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I know I can use a FTP program but Caja just works great.

Comment: Is the `gvfs-backends` package installed?

Comment: Yes, "gvfs-backends is already the newest version (1.48.2-0ubuntu1)."